# Why doesn't this MSDN sample work for me?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I'm trying the code sample (for ASP NET C#, for VS2010) from this page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx

And for anything I do the following line always evaluated to null:

```
if (Request.Form["ListBox1"] != null)
{
}
```

Can someone explain why?

Comment: Do you have the same exact markup from the MSDN example? If not, post the markup that you have.

Comment: The markup is the exact same. Please also see my response to the guy below...

Comment: [edit] The control markup and the code itself are the same. I'm adding it to a page generated from a master page in a default project template from VS2010.

Comment: @ahmd0 my mistake then. See how they are rendered on html

Comment: The name of the listbox becomes ctl00$MainContent$ListBox1 but that's not what I set up....

Comment: why don't you simply replace `Request.Form["ListBox1"]` by `ListBox1.SelectedValue` ?

Comment: @ahmd0 ASP.NET uses "naming containers" to build up the full control name to avoid duplicates. Certain controls, such as content place holders, are naming containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `null` because you are trying this example in a page that has a master page. If your page has a master page, controls rendered in the client side have a different ID. Since the `Request.Form` requires the `client Id` to access the value.

Comment: I cannot use ClientID from within InitializeCulture() override because no properties are yet set.

Comment: I have tell you the reason why you are getting null in my answer, but if you really want to get the value, you have to pass the Generated client ID

Comment: I mean you have to access the values like... Request.Form["should be rendered ClientID"]